# What does Working Context mean?

Tags: meaning

> The proposals aim to save £515,000 while creating a modern facilities management service for primary schools.
>
> The Glasgow City Council body Cordia has refused to pay janitors **Working Context** and Demands Payments, which range from £500 to £1,000 per year.
>
> Unison has said these payments would cost Cordia about £120,000 per year. [BBC](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-scotland-glasgow-west-39051103)

What does *Working Context* mean? I couldn't find clear answer on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is:

> Working Context and Demands

which are the conditions of work. and specific duties undertaken. in this case for janitors,

> Payment

is additional payment for work beyond what would normally be required.
Some information here: [Evening Times](http://www.eveningtimes.co.uk/news/14117230.Glasgow_jannies_want_extra_cash_for_cleaning_up_sick/)